# Populating a weekly shift schedule based on Availability

Tags: python

I manage a team of 4 and need to plug them into a weekly shift, one person on shift per day, and the maximum number of shifts per week they can do is 2. Prior to the week starting, they provide one of three availability statuses: "Preferred", "Unavailable", or just blank. If preferred, they get the shift, if unavailable they aren't an option. If blank, they are available if no one claimed it as preferred. I wrote the code below that populates each shift as it iterates through each team member's preferences. The problem I run into is that it isn't taking "Unavailable" into account and I don't want to overwrite someone else's shift with "Unavailable" because that would make it inaccurate. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
#Staff weekly preferences

BOB = {

    "Monday": "Preferred",
    "Tuesday": "Unavailable",
    "Wednesday": None,
    "Thursday": None,
    "Friday": "Preferred"
}

SUE = {

    "Monday": "Unavailable",
    "Tuesday": "Preferred",
    "Wednesday": None,
    "Thursday": None,
    "Friday": "Preferred"
}

JOHN = {

    "Monday": "Unavailable",
    "Tuesday": "Unavailable",
    "Wednesday": "Unavailable",
    "Thursday": "Unavailable",
    "Friday": "Unavailable"
}

BILLY = {

    "Monday": None,
    "Tuesday": None,
    "Wednesday": None,
    "Thursday": None,
    "Friday": None
}

SHIFT = {

    "Monday": None,
    "Tuesday": None,
    "Wednesday": None,
    "Thursday": None,
    "Friday": None
}





IGNORE = []

for key, value in BOB.items():
    if value == "Preferred":
        SUE[key] = "BOB"
        JOHN[key] = "BOB"
        BILLY[key] = "BOB"
        SHIFT[key] = "BOB"
    res = 0
    for key in SUE:
        if SUE[key] == "BOB":
            res = res + 1
        if res >= 2:
            IGNORE.append("BOB")
    if "BOB" not in IGNORE:
        if value == None:
            SUE[key] = "BOB"
            JOHN[key] = "BOB"
            BILLY[key] = "BOB"
            SHIFT[key] = "BOB"


for key, value in SUE.items():
    if value == "Preferred":
        JOHN[key] = "SUE"
        BILLY[key] = "SUE"
        SHIFT[key] = "SUE"
        res2 = 0
    for key, value in JOHN.items():
        if JOHN[key] == "SUE":
            res2 = res2 + 1
            if res2 >= 2:
                IGNORE.append("SUE")
        if "SUE" not in IGNORE:
            if value == None:
                JOHN[key] = "SUE"
                BILLY[key] = "SUE"
                SHIFT[key] = "SUE"


for key, value in JOHN.items():
    if value == "Preferred":
        BILLY[key] = "JOHN"
        SHIFT[key] = "JOHN"
        for key, value in BILLY.items():
            res3 = 0
            if BILLY[key] == "JOHN":
                res3 = res3 + 1
            if res3 >= 2:
                IGNORE.append("JOHN")
            if "JOHN" not in IGNORE:
                if value == None:
                    BILLY[key] = "JOHN"
                    SHIFT[key] = "JOHN"

for key, value in BILLY.items():
    if value == "Preferred":
        SHIFT[key] = "BILLY"
    for key, value in SHIFT.items():
        res4 = 0
        if SHIFT[key] == "BILLY":
            res4 = res4 + 1
            if res4 >= 2:
                IGNORE.append("BILLY")
        if "BILLY" not in IGNORE:
            if value == None:
                SHIFT[key] = "BILLY"
    
    
        



print(SHIFT)
```

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to solve an optimization problem.  There are packages designed to solve exactly such a task.  For example https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling

Comment: Looks like you need to fire John

Comment: thanks @Chris, I saw that before and I thought it was too complex for what I was trying to do here and was looking for something simpler

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Constraint Satisfaction Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) and you can easily solve it with [python-constraint](https://github.com/python-constraint/python-constraint) once you set up your problem properly.

Specifically, you can identify your variables as the days of the week `['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']` and your domain is the availability of each worker for that day, for example for the variable `Monday` the domain is `['Bob', 'Billy']` because both `Sue` and `John` are unavailable.

So, at first, we check if someone claimed a day with `Preferred` and we mark as `Unavailable` who left that day blank. Then, we convert the preferences in domains and we solve the problem. Once you get all the possible solutions, you remove the ones in which a worker has more than 2 shifts. At this point you will have a pool of candidate schedules from which you can choose your preferred one.

You can also implement a function to consider

> If preferred, they get the shift

but for this you need to be careful because you need another constraint/criterion to choose the worker when more than one preferred a given day. For example, both `Bob` and `Sue` prefer `Friday`, who does get that shift?

`schedule_solution.py`

```
from constraint import *

def get_schedule(team: dict, max_shifts: int):

    # working week, i.e., the variables
    week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

    # convert None to Unavailable if someone claimed the day with Preferred
    for worker in team:
        for day in week:
            if team[worker][day] is None:
                for colleague in team:
                    if worker != colleague and team[colleague][day] == 'Preferred':
                        team[worker][day] = 'Unavailable'

    # people available in each day, i.e., the domains
    domains = {}
    for day in week:
        domain = []
        for name in list(team.keys()):
            if team[name][day] != 'Unavailable':
                domain.append(name)
            domains[day] = domain

    # set up the CSP problem
    problem = Problem()

    # add the variables and the related domains
    for day in week:
        problem.addVariable(variable=day, domain=domains[day])

    # get all solutions
    solutions = problem.getSolutions()

    # get actual schedule considering the max_shifts
    schedule = []
    for solution in solutions:
        is_valid = True
        for name in list(team.keys()):
            shifts = 0
            for day in solution:
                if solution[day] == name:
                    shifts += 1
            if shifts > max_shifts:
                is_valid = False
                break
        if is_valid:
            schedule.append(solution)

    # re-arrange day order (python-constraint is changing it, I don't know why)
    for idx, element in enumerate(schedule):
        ordered = {}
        for day in week:
            ordered[day] = element[day]
        schedule[idx] = ordered

    # function return
    return schedule
```

`main.py`

```
from schedule_solution import get_schedule

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create team (I created a dictionary 'team' so that the problem can be general)
    bob = {'Monday': 'Preferred', 'Tuesday': 'Unavailable', 'Wednesday': None, 'Thursday': None, 'Friday': 'Preferred'}
    sue = {'Monday': 'Unavailable', 'Tuesday': 'Preferred', 'Wednesday': None, 'Thursday': None, 'Friday': 'Preferred'}
    john = {'Monday': 'Unavailable', 'Tuesday': 'Unavailable', 'Wednesday': 'Unavailable', 'Thursday': 'Unavailable', 'Friday': 'Unavailable'}
    billy = {'Monday': None, 'Tuesday': None, 'Wednesday': None, 'Thursday': None, 'Friday': None}
    team = {'Bob': bob, 'Sue': sue, 'John': john, 'Billy': billy}

    # set maximum shifts per week
    max_shifts = 2

    # get schedule
    schedule = get_schedule(team, max_shifts)

    # print schedule
    for element in schedule:
        print(element)
```

The schedule candidates are:

```
{'Monday': 'Bob', 'Tuesday': 'Sue', 'Wednesday': 'Billy', 'Thursday': 'Billy', 'Friday': 'Sue'}
{'Monday': 'Bob', 'Tuesday': 'Sue', 'Wednesday': 'Bob', 'Thursday': 'Billy', 'Friday': 'Sue'}
{'Monday': 'Bob', 'Tuesday': 'Sue', 'Wednesday': 'Billy', 'Thursday': 'Bob', 'Friday': 'Sue'}
{'Monday': 'Bob', 'Tuesday': 'Sue', 'Wednesday': 'Billy', 'Thursday': 'Billy', 'Friday': 'Bob'}
{'Monday': 'Bob', 'Tuesday': 'Sue', 'Wednesday': 'Sue', 'Thursday': 'Billy', 'Friday': 'Bob'}
{'Monday': 'Bob', 'Tuesday': 'Sue', 'Wednesday': 'Billy', 'Thursday': 'Sue', 'Friday': 'Bob'}
```